# Not understanding definition of expected value for X^2

Tags: probability, statistics

Context of this question is that I am trying to write the definition of $E[X^2]$.

I thought it would be $E[X^2] = \sum_i x_i^2 P(X^2 = x_i^2)$, but I see examples where it is actually $E[X^2] = \sum_i x_i^2 P(X = x_i)$ and I'm confused about the $P(X = x_i)$ part.

Is this written this way because $X = x_i$ is in correspondence with $X^2 = x_i^2$? Or am I missing something more fundamental?

Comment: If $X$ takes the values $+2$ or $-2$ each with probability $\frac12$ then your  $\sum_i x_i^2 P(X^2 = x_i^2)$ might be read as $(+2)^2P(X^2=4)+(-2)^2P(X^2=4)=4\times 1+4\times 1 =8$ when you clearly want the answer to be $E[X^2]=4$

Answer (score 1):

This is because of something that is apparently sometimes called the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), which states that:

$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \sum_y y P(g(X) = y) = \sum_x g(x) P(X = x)$

In other words, rather than having to calculate $P(X^2 = y)$ to directly calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, we can instead calculate the expectation using the probabilities $P(X = x)$.

And you are right - it *is* because there's a correspondence between $X$ and $X^2$ - for every possible value of $y = g(x)$, you can consider $P(g(X) = y) = \sum_{x : g(x) = y} P(X = x)$, i.e. it's the sum of the probabilities of all the values of $x$ that give $g(x) = y$.